# Symfony listener sees unchanged date field as changed, while both new and old date value are identical

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, listener

Maybe someone can help me understand something I can't explain on a Symfony listener. Here is the subject:

I have an entity product, which have a fields : `$creationDate` and a `$name`.

I also have a `ProductListener` to execute some other action upon entity changes.

Now I want to update this product name, so in my form I simply enter the new name, click validate and the process goes on, without changing the name.

After some digging, I've found it comes from the ProductListener, at some point of my code I have :

```
if ($event->hasChangedField('productCreationDate')) {
    $this->handleModification();
}
```

While I try to update the `$name` of the product, the `ProductListener` consider that the `$creationDate` have been changed (it did not). If I comment this condition, the update of the `$name` happens correctly.

So I know the issue comes from this condition, the question is why does it enter it in the first place, when the `$creationDate` field has not been changed.

So I searched why the listener believed the `$creationDate` field had been updated. I noticed the timezone of old and new values of this field were different so I updated the code as follow to make sure both were on timezone UTC:

```
/**
 *
 * @var DateTimeImmutable
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime_immutable", nullable=false)
 * @Groups({"product.write", "product.read"})
 * @ApiProperty(attributes={"normalization_context"={
 *  "datetime_format"="Y-m-d H:i:s",
 *  },
 * })
 */
private $dateCreation;
```

It fixed the timezone difference between old and new value of this field.

But the problem still occurs. Through my debug I managed to see the new and old value of the field `$creationDate` which are both equal to :

```
date="2020-07-01 00:00:00.000000"
timezone_type={int}3
timezone="UTC"

date="2020-07-01 00:00:00.000000"
timezone_type={int}3
timezone="UTC"
```

The fact that the date is in the future is normal. But nevertheless, both of those dates are identical, I can't find why the hasChangeField method of the event object would see it as changed.

The other methods of the `ProductListener` does not regard the `$creationDate` field. I do not have other doctrine lifecycle events.

Has this happened to anyone already? Does anyone have some hints or solutions? Thanks!

Comment: This is a complete shot in the dark, but could it be because of the declaration of the date as `immutable`? The `2020-07-01` value is still weird, though.

Comment: I don't think your source code shows the whole picture. What else do you have going on in the controller? You mentioned a form, what fields is this taking? Do you have any Doctrine lifecycle event functions, such as `PostLoad` running?

Comment: Withdrawing immutable does not change much regarding this issue, thanks though! @msg

Comment: @Adambean I've updated my issue as best I could to respond to your comment, no lifecyle event running, and the form not being the source of the issue

Comment: I think we'd need to see more of your controller and event listener to get an accurate picture of how your application is flowing. `DateTimeImmutable` isn't incorrect, but even changing `DateTime` would still be relevant if cloned/fresh instances are being made unexpectedly.